# Apache POI ClasDefNotFoundException when in fat jar compiled with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-poi

I had a pom.xml that was previously working, creating a fat .jar library with all the dependencies I need inside of it. Then I needed to use the library Apache POI, then I added this to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, using Eclipse, I run my JUnit tests, that covered the code which I am with the problem. Ok, then I run a Maven Build using Eclipse and then copied the .jar to the place where I am using.

When I called it, I got this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPackagePropertiesMarshaller
>     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.(OPCPackage.java:142)
>     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.(Package.java:37)     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:88)    at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:273)     at
>   org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:273)
>     at
>   com.foo.bar.util.FooBar.myMethod(FooBar.java:62) at
>   ...

The code snippet that has the problem is this, in its first line, when creating XSSFWorkbook:

```
public static Sheet myMethod(File fileEntry) {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(fileEntry));
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        return sheet;
}
```

Then again, the tests I wrote passed inside Eclipse. The whole pom.xml is bellow:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>bar/name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
  </properties>



<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.json</include>
                <include>**/*.json</include>
            </includes>


        </resource>

    </resources>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>uber-${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <!-- <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix> -->
                <!-- <mainClass>test.org.Cliente</mainClass> -->
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Class-Path>lib/</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <source>8</source>
              <target>8</target>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
    <artifactId>unitils-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>28.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Why are you using an ancient version of Apache POI with known security issues? Why not upgrade to a modern supported version?

Comment: Good question. I don't know why. I have changed this. Same error.

Comment: can you provide the full stack trace instead of snipping it?

Comment: After that line, the stack trace is on my code.